# Error propagation in an equation without an analytical solution

Tags: error-propagation

Is it possible to formally propagate uncertainties through an equation which does not have an analytical solution? I am an Earth Scientist working on doing a rigorous determination of the age calculated using (U-Th)/He dating, which uses the equation

$$
He = 8*^{238}U(e^{\lambda_{238}t}-1)\times7*^{235}U(e^{\lambda_{235}t}-1)\times6*^{232}Th(e^{\lambda_{232}t}-1)\times^{147}Sm(e^{\lambda_{147}t}-1)
$$

We solve for t numerically because the equation cannot be solved for t explicitly. The other variables (e.g., He, 238U, lambda238) are measured or known, each with their own uncertainty. For the sake of argument, let's say that I know the uncertainty on each value perfectly and all are gaussian. Is there a way to determine the uncertainty in t using "classical error propagation" (e.g., adding in quadrature) without the ability to solve for it explicitly? I know I could build a monte carlo code to figure it out, but I'm wondering if it's even possible to determine the uncertainty analytically.